# Floating a Table Element Issue (Form)

Tags: php, html, css

I can't seem to be able to get the alignment right on the below form:

http://penarthpc.com/~dronebo2/wp/shop/checkout/

(Shipping Address & Billing Address)

I can't figure out how to assign a value to the input fields within that class only ( to align/float them to the left not the right as they are now).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You'd better include a screenshot and the relevant html / css as that link takes you to an empty cart.

Comment: Why are they floated right? `input.text` has a `float:right` property. Is that supposed to be there? You could add another class `.wpsc_checkout_table input.left` with `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

You can float them right by adding the following rule to your CSS

```
#checkout_page_container .wpsc_checkout_table input {
     float:left;
}
```

Comment: Haha, damnit! Well I was close at least... I only gave him the exact opposite of what he wanted :)
I've edited it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have `.wpsc_checkout_table input {}` and `.wpsc_checkout_table input.text {}` inside of your CSS file. Since `.wpsc_checkout_table input.text {}` is more explicit, it chooses that for it's styling. Remove the `float:right` within `.wpsc_checkout_table input.text {}` and everything will work correctly.